# Theme-Chooser in Github - to choose a jekyll-theme vanished

Tags: html, github, jekyll, github-pages

I am currently setting up a page and I wonder where the GitHub *theme-chooser* has gone. According to the following instruction, I want to go through the process:

[image]

It seems that the theme-chooser has been removed. I want to use the jekyll-theme minimal (like caroly stransky does).

[image]

Is this documentation still correct and is the information still relevant?

update: see here the image of how it looks here [image]

i want to add the line that carol did in the configuration; Christian it would be awesome if you can help here...

**second update:** hi there  - since i cannot see the config.yml i think that i have to add the additional line to the so called raw file: see below the image

[image]

can you confirm that is that all right!?
love to hear from you

[image]

**update3:**  well i guess that i ll need to create a new file named "_config.yml" and with this i ll ned to set it's contents to this: ´theme: jekyll-theme-minimal`´ I guess that i have to do this

update4: well i ve created the file - and i guess this is done right - but wait. I have to edit this file correctly

```
theme: jekyll-theme-minimal
```

Well i need to add this correctly - not as comment but as content of the file... This is pretty important.

[image]

Comment: hi Christian - many thanks - awesome: i am trying to recapitulate and to reproduce what carol did - i want to apply it on the page: https://github.com/fsj-digital/DigitalHub which is pretty in beta beta - i want to add a theme like carol did - so it would be good if i can find the main/_config.yml - - i will try and  in the afternoon i will try to follow your steps youve  written in your answer - i come back later the day..

Comment: I have updated my answer with links to my repo. I think you can still use `theme: jekyll-theme-minima` as in the config in the blog post. In my case, I followed the current readme and use the remote repo in my configuration.

Comment: well i guess that i ll need to create a new file named "_config.yml" and with this i ll ned to set it's contents to this:

´theme: jekyll-theme-minimal`´

I guess that i have to do this

Answer (score 1):

The blog post (workwithcarolyn.com/blog/digital-cv-guide) is from 2020. The displayed images are outdated. In a test repo I couldn't find the option to select a theme anymore. The new pages setup page (https://github.com/YOURUSER/REPOSITORY/settings/pages) just contains a link to the docs:

[image]

The [link to the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/adding-a-theme-to-your-github-pages-site-using-jekyll) explains how to set a theme for your site. Under point 5 the page says:

> Add a new line to the file for the theme name.
>
> To use a supported theme, type theme: THEME-NAME, replacing THEME-NAME with the name of the theme as shown in the README of the theme's repository. For a list of supported themes, see ["Supported themes"](https://pages.github.com/themes/) on the GitHub Pages site.

The supported themes page is linking to the repository of each theme.

Some other themes are remote themes, e.g. [Minimal](https://github.com/pages-themes/minimal). The repository explains how to add the theme:

> To use the Minimal theme:
> Add the following to your site's _config.yml:

```
remote_theme: pages-themes/minimal@v0.2.0  
plugins:  
  - jekyll-remote-theme
```

You can have a look at https://github.com/cadamini/test/blob/main/_config.yml  and the resulting page at https://cadamini.github.io/test/

Comment: awesome - dear Christian you have helped me alot. I am trying to get the grip. I will try to find the process in your demo and test account. 

I will reply later the afternoon - meanwhile - many many thanks  for all you did.

Comment: Hi Chriastian - your test looks really awesome  - i will do as your recommend - and att the following lines to the site configs.yml -

Comment: dear christian,  
**second update:** hi there  - since i cannot see the config.yml i think that i have to add the additional line to the so called raw file: see below the image

see the added image in the second update: 

can you confirm that is that all right!?
love to hear from you

Comment: Correct, update the file content

Comment: finally - it worked: i am very glad - i have learned alot. Many thanks for your awesome and continued support. - Great!